# A land characterized by many contrasts

Tags: verb, conjugation

Afghanistan ist ein Land, das viele Gegensätze bestimmt. Auf dem Land und vor allem in den abgelegenen Gegenden der Gebirge gibt es noch sehr viele traditionelle Vorstellungen und die Menschen leben wie vor hunderten von Jahren. In Großstädten wie Kabul ist das Leben viel westlicher geprägt, es handelt sich um eine moderne Großstadt.

Would you agree that, given the context, they should have used the plural of bestimmen in the first sentence? I.e. that it is the Gegensätze that characterize the country, and not the country that characterizes the Gegensätze.

Source: https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/afghanistan/alltag-kinder/probleme/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I agree. The subject of the subordinate clause is clearly "viele Gegensätze", so the predicate should also be in plural. The relative pronoun "das" is the accusative object.

> Afghanistan ist ein Land, das viele Gegensätze bestimmen.

Passive voice would be more readable here in my opinion:

> Afghanistan ist ein Land, das von vielen Gegensätzen bestimmt wird.